# React Navigation drawer goes blank after adding contentComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation to create custom NavigationDrawer with a header on top this is how my code looks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import AboutScreen from './modules/screens/About/index'
import ContactScreen from './modules/screens/Contact/index'
import HomeScreen from './modules/screens/Home/index'

import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from "react-navigation";

import { Image, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

class NewDrawer extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <AppDrawer />
        );
    }
}
const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    AboutScreen: AboutScreen,
    ContactScreen: ContactScreen,

},
    //Commenting below part makes my code work
    {
        contentComponent: CustomDrawer
    }
)
const CustomDrawer = (props) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Image source={require('./modules/images/header.jpeg')}
                style={{ height: 120, width: 120 }}>
            </Image>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
            <DrawerItems {...props}>

            </DrawerItems>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)

export default NewDrawer;
```

[image]

If I remove `contentComponent` i see my drawer items.

How can I get Header with custom drawer item?

> I am using:-
>
> npm > v6.4.1
>
> Node > v8.12.0
>
> react-navigation > v2.17.0

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uhJN4kVS6g)

Comment: https://youtu.be/Gz1IXbjpb2c

Comment: I am already following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uhJN4kVS6g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending props to **CustomDrawer** . Try code below.

```
contentComponent: props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem but its nowhere mentioned in the official document or the tutorial video that I'm following

Comment: Welcome. Yes you are right , official document only state that custom drawer take props.  But different code is available on net about sending props to custom  drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Drawer.js

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Image source={require('./modules/images/header.jpeg')}
            style={{ height: 120, width: 120 }}>
        </Image>
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
        <DrawerItems {...props}>

        </DrawerItems>
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

App.js

```
import CustomDrawer from './Drawer' // Import the file

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    AboutScreen: AboutScreen,
    ContactScreen: ContactScreen,

},
    {
        contentComponent: <CustomDrawer />
    }
)
```

This should work tested on android device

Comment: I got an error saying "Check the render method of DrawerSidebar"

Comment: Try alternate way